# on clicking the link current page url is also added to the upcoming page on redirection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, api

i'm trying to redirect to new page on clicking the link, but it redirect to new page it also add previous page url in the address bar. Kindly have a look at my code. How do i remove current page url on the upcoming page or next page.

This my HTML.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "ProductList";
}
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Product List</h2>
<div  id="im" >

</div>
```

Here is my Script.

```
  <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var loc = window.location.href;
            var dat = loc.substring(loc.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            $.ajax({
                url:'api-url'
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: JSON.stringify({ "ProjectId": "1", "CategoryId": dat }),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    $.each(data.ProductList, function () {
                        var list = "<a href='Product/ProductDetail/" + this.Id + "'><img src=" + this.ImageLink + " height=400 width=400> " + this.Name + "</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; $" + this.Price + " </img> ";
                        $("#im").append(list);
                    })
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

On Redirection the next page url becomes like this.

```
http://localhost:36547/Product/ProductList/Product/ProductDetail/102
```

Rather it should be

```
http://localhost:36547/Product/ProductDetail/102
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add slash `/` before product url to route from domain root

```
var list = "<a href='/Product/ProductDetail/" + this.Id + "'><img src=" + this.ImageLink + " height=400 width=400> " + this.Name + "</a>&nbsp; &nbsp; $" + this.Price + " </img> ";
$("#im").append(list);
```

Without it browser URL will be relative to the current path

Comment: This really should have been a comment.

Comment: @Luke sure, I added explanation for that

Comment: @SaqibMajeed Glad it works! Please, do not forget accept the answer

Comment: @hmnzr The problem is that I fear that this question/answer isn't going to be useful to anyone in the future.

Comment: @hmnzr sure i will. You saved my time. i was trying to solve this from 3 hours.